# Python Wiki Path Searching

Tags: python, performance, url, beautifulsoup

On a personal whim I have written some code to search for the shortest series of links between any two Wikipedia articles. It turned out to be very brute force and takes a long long time to find the goal if it's more than a link or two deep, but it works! I will eventually keep track of and make use of the link paths and stuff, but I wanted to get the search working optimally first. Is there a faster way to do this or a good way to cut some major corners here?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Start = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Reid_%28politician%29'
End = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayr'

#Using BeautifulSoup, this grabs the page
def soup_request(target):
    request = urllib2.Request(target)
    request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
    page = urllib2.urlopen(target)
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(page)
    return soup

#This will grab all Wiki links off a given page
def get_links(Start):
    soup = soup_request(Start)
    Wiki_links = []
    #Finds all links
    for url in soup.findAll('a'):
        result = url.get('href')
        try:
            if str(result)[:5] == '/wiki':
                Wiki_links.append(result)
        except:
            pass
    for q in range(len(Wiki_links)):
        Wiki_links[q] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org'+str(Wiki_links[q])
    print "Got new links from",Start
    return Wiki_links

#This will check all the given links to see if the title matches the goal webpage
def check_links(Links,End):
    goalsoup = soup_request(End)
    goaltitle = goalsoup.html.title
    Found = False
    count = 0
    for q in Links:
        if Found:
            break
        length = len(Links)
        #Runs through all the given links and checks their titles for correct one
        if q is not None:
            count += 1
            soup = soup_request(q)
            print "Checked",count,"links out of",length
            try:
                title = soup.html.head.title
                if title == goaltitle:
                    Found = True
                    print "Found it!"
                    break
            except:
                print 'doh'
                pass
    return Found

#Top function to do all the stuff in the right order, applying a maximum depth of how deep into the links
def wiki_crawl(Start, End, depth):
    Old_Links = [Start]
    count = depth
    while count > 0:
        New_Links = []
        for q in range(len(Old_Links)):
            New_Links.extend(get_links(Old_Links[q]))
        Found = check_links(New_Links,End)
        if Found:
            print "All done."
            break
        Old_Links = New_Links
        count -= 1
        print "_______________________________________________________________ROUND DONE"
    if not Found:
        print "Did not find the page, you must go deeper!"

wiki_crawl(Start, End, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some functions to take info from wiki.  The only problems with it is that sometimes it takes out a space from the info on the webpage.

```
def take_out_parenthesis(st):
string = list(st)
for a in string:
    if a == '(':
        del string[st.find(a)]
    if a == ')':
        del string[st.find(a) - 1]
return ''.join(string)


def take_out_tags(string):
    st = list(string)
    odd = ['<', '>']
    times = 0
    for a in string:
        if a in odd:
            times += 1
    times /= 2
    for b in range(times):
        start = string.find('<') - 1
        end = string.find('>')
        bet = end - start + 1
        for a in range(bet):
            del st[start]
        string = ''.join(st)
    return string


def take_out_brackets(string):
    st = list(string)
    odd = ['[', ']']
    times = 0
    for a in string:
        if a in odd:
            times += 1
    times /= 2
    for b in range(times):
        start = string.find('[') - 1
        end = string.find(']')
        bet = end - start + 1
        for a in range(bet):
            del st[start]
        string = ''.join(st)
    return string


def take_from_web_page(text):
    n = 0
    url = text.replace(" ", "_")
    search = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s" % url
    page = urllib2.urlopen(search).read()
    start = page.find('<p><b>') + 6
    end = page.find('</a>.', start) + 5
    new_page = page[start:end]
    for a in new_page:
        if a == '<':
            if new_page[n - 1] != ' ':
                lst = list(new_page)
                lst.insert(n, ' ')
                new_page = ''.join(lst)
                n += 1
        n += 1
    return take_out_parenthesis(take_out_brackets(take_out_tags(new_page)))
```